# How do I change the form of Deoxys in Pokémon X and Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

How can I change the form of Deoxys in Pokémon X and Y? In previous games there are meteorites that, upon touching, cause its form to change. Is there something similar to this in Pokémon X and Y?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From serebii: http://www.serebii.net/xy/bankunlocks.shtml

> In the Fossil Lab in Ambrette Town, in the north-west part of the lab
>   you will find various Meteorites. Four of these meteorites will allow
>   you to change Deoxys' form between its four forms: Normal, Attack,
>   Defense and Speed Formes.

[image: Deoxys Meteorites]

Comment: Once I test it out, I will accept accordingly.

Comment: Each one is not assigned to a form, they all cause him to cycle to the next one.